# Client side alphabetic multi-column (lists) sorting and filtering

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, client-side

I have an index of "services" which is quite large, and I am trying to make it user friendly.

The current display is four columns (four unordered lists, at the moment) that displays alphabetically top to bottom, then left to right like so:

```
Ab      Be      Co      En
Ac      Ce      De      Fa
Af      Ci      Ef      Gu
```

These lists are built in the C# code behind, then the BulletedList controls are attached to the containing Panel control on page load.

The number of items has become large enough that we want to make use of filtering giving a list across the top for # A B C D... etc, and when you click on it, it will filter the results. We want to accomplish this using JavaScript, and avoiding post backs.

My initial thought was to have JavaScript (jQuery) simply .show() and .hide() the ones necessary, but with the current unordered list arrangement, I am struggling with how to accomplish this and maintain the alphabetic layout.

For example, using the four unordered lists example above, filtering for A would result in just this:

```
Ab
Ac
Af
```

instead of spanning across the columns.

Taking the thought further, I considered using a single unordered list and having list items float left to easily span across the screen and then down -- but the issue I run into that is sorting alphabetically down first and then across, because it sorts across first and then down.

Additionally, using the float left method causes any link that spans two lines to cause an extra line break for all links across the row, resulting in odd gaps.

I realize this is fairly long winded and specific question, but any assistance on how to accomplish this with code, html/css formatting, or suggestions for a better way of doing this is much appreciated! Thanks for taking the time to read the question.

Comment: It seems really odd (from a UX standpoint) that you'd arrange the items horizontally, but order them vertically.  Anyway, I'm not sure it would be easy (or even possible) with markup -- I'd probably go with a JQuery approach that  generates the markup each time the filter changes.

Comment: @McGarnagle I actually had it alphabetically left to right originally, but my supervisor did not like that the items were ending up not completely in line (they staggered a little) when some items were spanning two lines, which is understandable.

Perhaps the "gaps" we were seeing before with left float list items would actually be useful in keeping them lined lined up.

Comment: If they need to be lined up, then why not use a table?  Might make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use one of the jquery portfolio plugins.

Here's one example: http://webdesigntunes.com/coding/jquery-filterable-portfolio/

You create some html tagged with classes matching what you want to sort on

```
<nav class="primary clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".ill">Ilustration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".logo">Logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".video">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".print">Print Design</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section class="main">

            <div class="portfolio">

                <article class="entry video">
                    <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://vimeo.com/34266952">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/work1.jpg" alt="">
                    <span class="video-hover"></span>
                    </a>
                </article>

                <article class="entry web">
                    <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="images/portfolio/work2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/work2.jpg" alt="">
                    <span class="magnifier"></span>
                    </a>
                </article>
</section>
```

Apply some .css ect.

Then use isotope for sorting

```
 var $container = $('.portfolio');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
    });

    $('nav.primary ul a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false,
            }
        });
      return false;
    });

    var $optionSets = $('nav.primary ul'),
           $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

           $optionLinks.click(function(){
              var $this = $(this);
          // don't proceed if already selected
          if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
              return false;
          }
       var $optionSet = $this.parents('nav.primary ul');
       $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
       $this.addClass('selected');
    });
```

CHeck out the demo and see if that's what you're needing: http://webdesigntunes.com/tutorial/filterable/

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: This answer is fantastic. Thanks a bunch for a detailed and helpful answer!

Comment: No problem, if you have issues let me know